# How to insert json object containing $ as value in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have to add couple of values as currency in cassandara db through datastax one of which has $ as value. But it is failing.

```
INSERT INTO concept_value_set (concept_name,value_set) 
    VALUES ('@CurrencyType',{'Dollar', 'Usd', 'Euro', 
    'Pound', 'Frank', 'Renminbi', '$'});
```

This causes issue with the system.

I tried to escape `$` using

```
INSERT INTO concept_value_set (concept_name,value_set) 
   VALUES ('@CurrencyType',{'Dollar', 'Usd', 'Euro', 
   'Pound', 'Frank', 'Renminbi', '$$'});
```

but it fails too.

Is there a way to escape `$` here. I could not find any proper links on it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the dollar sign is your problem here.  I think it's in how the JSON value is using single quotes.  Rebuilding your table (based on the info provided), I came up with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE concept_value_set (
  concept_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  value_set TEXT);
```

And I was able to get this to work:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO concept_value_set JSON '{
    "\"concept_name\"":"@CurrencyType",
    "\"value_set\"":"Dollar, Usd, Euro, Pound, Frank, Renminbi, $"}';
```

Now, I can query the table for TEXT:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM concept_value_set
                             WHERE concept_name='@CurrencyType';

 concept_name  | value_set
---------------+----------------------------------------------
 @CurrencyType | Dollar, Usd, Euro, Pound, Frank, Renminbi, $

(1 rows)
```

The table can also be queried for JSON, like this:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT JSON value_set FROM concept_value_set
                             WHERE concept_name='@CurrencyType';

 [json]
---------------------------------------------------------------
 {"value_set": "Dollar, Usd, Euro, Pound, Frank, Renminbi, $"}

(1 rows)
```

You can find more info on working with JSON in Cassandra on the main [Apache Cassandra project documentation site](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cql/json.html), as well as on DataStax's documentation site: ([INSERT JSON](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html), [QUERY JSON](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryJSON.html)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: the table ddl is CREATE TABLE  concept_value_set (
 concept_name text,
 value_set SET<text>,
 PRIMARY KEY (concept_name)
)